# Gâteaux differentiable at $0$, but not Fréchet differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I'm struggling to prove that $ \varphi\left ( a,b \right )= \frac{x^{3}y}{x^{4}+y^{2}} $ is Gâteaux differentiable at $0$, but not Fréchet differentiable. In other examples that I studied, proving that the function wasn't continuous at $(0,0)$ and that it was Gâteaux differentiable at the same point was sufficient, but I am having trouble to prove the continuity of the function above in $(0,0)$

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Continuity at $(0,0)$ is easy: $2x^{2} |y| \leq x^{4}+y^{2}$ so $|\phi (a,b) | \leq \frac 1 2 |x| \to 0$.